# bulk edit crawlability of pdf's in AEM

Tags: aem

Is there a way to bulk edit a few hundreds of pdfs in Adobe experience manager - we want search engine bots not to crawl them but still searchable in internal search. But instead of doing it manually, is there a way we can bulk edit them in cUrl or any other easy way?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way?